# Move a UITableView down 44pix using

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I am using a Storyboard to create all my tables but I need to move the tables down the page to insert a UIView above each table. This was trivial using a nib and Interface builder or in code but I can't seem to do it via interface build and story boards. OK so then I try to do it code and no luck there either:

In viewDidLoad:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y + 44.0f, frame.size.width,
                             frame.size.height - 44.0f);
```

If I check both self.view.frame and self.tableView.frame they have been re-sized, yet when the table displays nothing happen.

I have searched around but haven't found a solution so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add your `UIView` in table header `tableHeaderView`.

Also, set custom height to the table header - sectionHeaderHeight:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 50.0;
}
```